# How to override the woocommerce.css in the parent theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using an ecommerce enabled [wordpress theme](http://themeisle.com/themes/shop-isle/)! for my website along with woocommerce. Have created a childtheme, copied woocommerce.css(from the woocommerce plugin) to the child theme css and disabled the enqueuing of this woocommerce.css.

There is a woocommerce.css in my parent theme's folder structure also ( ~/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/inc/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css).How do i override this so as to be agnostic to any theme updates?

Also - what is the difference between the woocommerce.css in the parent theme folder structure and in the woocommerce plugin folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the same file in your child theme, so you will have something like this:

```
~/wp-content/themes/shop-isle-child/inc/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css
```

This way the *woocommerce.css* of the parent theme will not matter.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: But unfortunately this approach is not working. I replicated the directory structure, but the changes done in the child theme css are not being reflected.

Comment: @SaurabhJindal look at how you can disable the originals: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/

Comment: this talks about overriding the woocommerce plugin's css. My theme is using a woocommerce css in its own folder structure - and I need to override that. I can;t find the name for this css so that I could try the unsetting of the enqueuing of this css and then enqueue the same css in my child theme. Hope I could make myself clear here.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried this approach deactivating the cache plugin Autoptimize?

Comment: I don't have AutoOptimize on my local machine. Can't edit css with it being active.

Comment: So what do you have in you production site to manage the caché, there is something that is playing with the CSS.

Comment: I am using w3 total cache plugin in production. But I can override the parent theme css in the child theme - so guess w3tc should not be an issue.

Comment: Try to disable it and see what happens, also why don't you just delete the woocommerce.css (back it up of course) to see if Wordpress sees the css in the childtheme.

Comment: Deleting the woocommerce.css is a temporary solution because it will be there again when the parent theme update happens.

Comment: I tried using get_stylesheet_directory() after replicating the 'inc' folder structure - it works on the php files and I can override them, but not for the css. In fact if I overrride the parent folder css ( in the inc folder), it shows the whole css on my web-page.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried various things, including using the get_stylesheet_directory() function - but nothing worked. I contacted the theme guys, and they gave me this code to override the woocommerce.css in the inc folder after replicating the folder structure in the child-theme, and it seems to work.

```
function ti_dequeue_script() {
  wp_dequeue_script( 'shop-isle-woocommerce-style1' );
    }
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'ti_dequeue_script', 100 );

function ti_enqueue_script() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'shop-isle-woocommerce-style2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css',array(), 'v3' );
   }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ti_enqueue_script', 100 );
```